# Write APN Settings on Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, telephony

Is it possible to write APN programmatically on Android 4.4? 
I noticed that the Telephony.Carriers is available for API level 19.

Answer (score 0):

I have a software with APN write feature. Since Android 4.0 you can write APN settings only if you have system permissions. My software was designed to be a system software, so I can write APN and other settings. But, this feature is no longer working in Android 4.4 and I don't know why yet.

After read the Telephony.Carriers class, I could not find a new way to write APN. It's just a class to tell you informations but can't change them.

My code to write APN is:

```
    public class APN {

    public static final int AUTH_TYPE_UNKNOW = -1;
    public static final int AUTH_TYPE_NONE = 0;
    public static final int AUTH_TYPE_PAP = 1;
    public static final int AUTH_TYPE_CHAP = 2;
    public static final int AUTH_TYPE_PAP_OR_CHAP = 3;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String apn;
    private String mcc;
    private String mnc;
    private String type;
    private String server;
    private String proxy;
    private String port;
    private String mmsProxy;
    private String mmsPort;
    private String mmsc;
    private String current;
    private int authType;

    public APN() {
        id = -1;
        name = "";
        user = "";
        password = "";
        apn = "";
        mcc = "";
        mnc = "";
        type = "default,supl";
        server = "";
        proxy = "";
        port = "";
        mmsProxy = "";
        mmsPort = "";
        mmsc = "";
        current = "";
        authType = AUTH_TYPE_NONE;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getApn() {
        return apn;
    }
    public void setApn(String apn) {
        this.apn = apn;
    }
    public String getMcc() {
        return mcc;
    }
    public void setMcc(String mcc) {
        this.mcc = mcc;
    }
    public String getMnc() {
        return mnc;
    }
    public void setMnc(String mnc) {
        this.mnc = mnc;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }
    public void setServer(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
    public String getProxy() {
        return proxy;
    }
    public void setProxy(String proxy) {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }
    public String getMmsProxy() {
        return mmsProxy;
    }
    public void setMmsProxy(String mmsProxy) {
        this.mmsProxy = mmsProxy;
    }
    public String getMmsPort() {
        return mmsPort;
    }
    public void setMmsPort(String mmsPort) {
        this.mmsPort = mmsPort;
    }
    public String getMmsc() {
        return mmsc;
    }
    public void setMmsc(String mmsc) {
        this.mmsc = mmsc;
    }
    public String getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }
    public void setCurrent(String current) {
        this.current = current;
    }
    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public int getAuthType() {
        return authType;
    }
    public void setAuthType(int authType) {
        this.authType = authType;
    }
}
```

and:

```
    public class APNUtils {

    private static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    private static final Uri APN_PREFER_URI = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn");

    private static ContentValues prepareValues(APN apn) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        if (!apn.getName().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("name", apn.getName());

        if (!apn.getApn().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("apn", apn.getApn());

        if (!apn.getMcc().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("mcc", apn.getMcc());

        if (!apn.getMnc().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("mnc", apn.getMnc());

        if (!apn.getMcc().trim().equals("") && !apn.getMnc().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("numeric", apn.getMcc() + apn.getMnc());

        if (!apn.getUser().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("user", apn.getUser());

        if (!apn.getPassword().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("password", apn.getPassword());

        if (!apn.getServer().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("server", apn.getServer());

        if (!apn.getProxy().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("proxy", apn.getProxy());

        if (!apn.getPort().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("port", apn.getPort());

        if (!apn.getMmsProxy().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("mmsproxy", apn.getMmsProxy());

        if (!apn.getMmsPort().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("mmsport", apn.getMmsPort());

        if (!apn.getMmsc().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("mmsc", apn.getMmsc());

        if (!apn.getType().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("type", apn.getType());

        if (!apn.getCurrent().trim().equals(""))
            values.put("current", apn.getCurrent());

        values.put("authtype", apn.getAuthType());

        return values;
    }

    public static int createNewApn(Context context, APN apn, boolean setAsDefaultAPN) {
        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn.");
        int apnid = -1;

        try {
            if (apn != null) {
                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Reading APN list.");
                Uri APN_URI = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers");
                ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Creating new registry based on parameters.");
                ContentValues values = prepareValues(apn);

                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Inserting new APN.");
                Cursor c = null;
                Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_URI, values);

                if(newRow != null) {
                    Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Getting new ID.");
                    c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);

                    int tableIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    apnid = c.getShort(tableIndex);
                } else
                    Logs.warningLog("APNutils.createNewApn. New APN was not found. Inserting failed?");

                if(c != null){
                    c.close();
                }

                if (apnid > -1 && setAsDefaultAPN) {
                    Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Setting new APN as default.");
                    ContentValues v = new ContentValues(1);
                    v.put("apn_id", apnid);

                    context.getContentResolver().update(APN_PREFER_URI, v, null, null);
                }
            } else
                Logs.warningLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Invalid apn (null).");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logs.errorLog("createNewApn: error", e);
        }

        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.createNewApn. Returning ID " + String.valueOf(apnid));
        return apnid;
    }   

    public static boolean updateApn(Context context, int id, APN apn) {
        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.updateApn.");

        if (apn != null) {
            try {
                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.updateApn. Reading APN list.");
                Uri APN_URI = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers");
                ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.updateApn. Creating new registry based on parameters.");
                ContentValues values = prepareValues(apn);

                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.updateApn. Inserting new APN.");
                int result = resolver.update(APN_URI, values, "_id = " + String.valueOf(id), null);

                if (result != -1) {
                    Logs.infoLog("APNutils.updateApn. APN updated.");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Logs.warningLog("APNutils.updateApn. Invalid ID (" + String.valueOf(id) + ").");
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logs.errorLog("APNUtils.updateApn error: ", e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            Logs.warningLog("APNutils.updateApn. Invalid apn (null).");

            return false;
        }
    }   

    public static boolean verifyApn(Context context, String apn) {
        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.verifyApn.");
        return getApn(context, apn) > -1;
    }

    public static int getApn(Context context, String apn) {
        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.getApn.");
        int result = -1;

        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.getApn. Looking for APN " + apn);
        String columns[] = new String[] { "_ID", "NAME" };
        String where = "name = ?";
        String wargs[] = new String[] { apn };
        String sortOrder = null;
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, columns, where, wargs, sortOrder);

        if (cur != null) {
            int tableIndex = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.getApn. APN found.");
                result = cur.getShort(tableIndex);
            }

            cur.close();
        } 

        if (result == -1)
            Logs.warningLog("APNutils.getApn. APN not found.");

        return result;  
    }

    public static boolean setPreferredApn(Context context, String apn) {
        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.setPreferredApn.");
        boolean changed = false;

        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.setPreferredApn. Looking for APN " + apn);
        String columns[] = new String[] { "_ID", "NAME" };
        String where = "name = ?";
        String wargs[] = new String[] { apn };
        String sortOrder = null;
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, columns, where, wargs, sortOrder);

        if (cur != null) {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                Logs.infoLog("APNutils.setPreferredApn. APN found. Setting as default.");
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
                values.put("apn_id", cur.getLong(0));

                if (context.getContentResolver().update(APN_PREFER_URI, values, null, null) == 1) {
                    Logs.infoLog("APNutils.setPreferredApn. APN marked as default.");
                    changed = true;
                }
            }

            cur.close();
        }

        if (!changed) 
            Logs.warningLog("APNutils.setPreferredApn. APN not found or could not be marked as default.");

        return changed; 
    }

    public static APN[] getAllApnList(Context context) {
        Logs.infoLog("APNutils.getAllApnList.");

        APN[] result = null;

        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/");

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try
        {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, 
                    new String[] {"_ID", "name", "apn", "mcc", "mnc", "numeric", "user", "password", "server", "proxy", 
                    "port", "mmsproxy", "mmsport", "mmsc", "type", "current", "authtype "}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                result = new APN[cursor.getCount()];
                int i = 0;

                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    APN apn = new APN();

                    apn.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    apn.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    apn.setApn(cursor.getString(2));
                    apn.setMcc(cursor.getString(3));
                    apn.setMnc(cursor.getString(4));
                    apn.setUser(cursor.getString(6));
                    apn.setPassword(cursor.getString(7));
                    apn.setServer(cursor.getString(8));
                    apn.setProxy(cursor.getString(9));
                    apn.setPort(cursor.getString(10));
                    apn.setMmsProxy(cursor.getString(11));
                    apn.setMmsPort(cursor.getString(12));
                    apn.setMmsc(cursor.getString(13));
                    apn.setType(cursor.getString(14));
                    apn.setCurrent(cursor.getString(15));
                    apn.setAuthType(cursor.getInt(16));

                    result[i] = apn;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle exceptions here
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cursor != null) 
                cursor.close();
        }       

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to use Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI instead of the hard-coded value.